# Why is the size() method of std::list O(n) in GCC?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, size, stdlist

In GCC the `size()` method of std::list is O(n). Why?

For C++11 the standard says [`size()` of list should be `O(1)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size)

However in glibc we have the following:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6.3/bits/stl_list.h

template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Tp> >
class list : protected _List_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
{
 ...
 size_type
  size() const
  { return std::distance(begin(), end()); }
```

The question is: How is it that the a three year old requirement is not yet implemented in GCC?

### EDIT:

gcc 5 changes this: though at the cost of ABI change; this means that C++ code compiled with gcc 5.0 will not work with older versions of the C++ runtime library.

From https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html

> A new implementation of `std::list` is enabled by default, with an O(1) `size()` function

Comment: g++ 4.5 is from 2010. Get a more recent version!

Comment: very nice, in 4.6.3 its the same thing

Comment: It's the same in 4.8.3!

Comment: Nitpicking: That should be `libstdc++`, not `glibc`.

Answer (score 8):

In C++98/03 it was unspecified as to whether `std::list::size()` is O(1) or O(N).  There are tradeoffs for either decision.

In C++11, the committee specified that `std::list::size()` is O(1).  This is an ABI-breaking change for implementations that have an O(N) `std::list::size()`, and gcc is such an implementation. Breaking ABI is a big deal for an implementor.  It causes a lot of pain for its customers.  So it is done only once in a big while, and with relatively big fanfare.

Comment: then how is it that they change the name mangling algorithm often?  you can't link a newer binary to a binary compiled with the old name mangling algorithm. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html

Comment: @MichaelMoser the name mangling is *not* specified by the standard. It's implementation-dependent.

Comment: @MarkRansom still in terms of being able to link to a binary compiled with an old version of the compiler it is just as breaking as an ABI change.

Comment: @MichaelMoser what I'm trying to tell you is that there are different people in charge of both decisions. They will have different priorities.

Comment: @MarkRansom you are right, the glibc developers are different from the gcc developers, i guess they are not too coordinated either.

Comment: @MichaelMoser:  Yes, sometimes ABI changes. And libstdc++ ABI will change in the future. It must change for both `list` and `string` to become C++11 conforming. The libstdc++ developers will decide when to throw that switch. I note from the link you gave that the default mangling was held steady from 3.4 through 4.9. That's about a decade.